# How much space does extended partition take to store logical partition table?

Tags: partitioning

When I typed `fdisk -l`, I got:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ec76e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2046   976771071   488384513    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            2048    39999487    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda6        40001536    42000383      999424   83  Linux
/dev/sda7        42002432    62001151     9999360   83  Linux
/dev/sda8        62003200    78002175     7999488   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9        78004224   976771071   449383424   83  Linux
```

but 488384513-(19998720+999424+9999360+7999488+449383424)=4097 which is an odd number!

Answer (score 2):

It takes almost next to nothing, a few bytes, a single 512 byte sector, but only because a sector is the smallest unit.

However it's a linked list so there is one such structure before each logical partition.

In conjunction with partition alignment to MiB boundaries which is common nowadays, you may end up with 1 MiB gaps between partitions, which seems to be your case.

As for unallocated / usable gaps, `parted` will show them (but not the alignment gaps).

```
# parted /dev/loop0 unit s print free
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 976773168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system  Flags
        63s         2045s       1983s                 Free Space
 1      2046s       976771071s  976769026s  extended               lba
 5      2048s       39999487s   39997440s   logical
 6      40001536s   42000383s   1998848s    logical
 7      42002432s   62001151s   19998720s   logical
 8      62003200s   78002175s   15998976s   logical
 9      78004224s   976771071s  898766848s  logical
        976771072s  976773167s  2096s                 Free Space
```

You could probably make 1 and 9 larger by 2048s (1MiB) but it's probably not worth the effort and leaving 1 MiB free between partitions and at the beginning and end of the disk does not have to be a bad thing.

Comment: A well-stated answer. I'll add that a typical 1MiB gap between logical partitions is puny. Prinz Km has a 500GB disk, which is smallish by today's standards, and on it, 1MiB of "wasted" disk space equates to 0.0002% of the disk's capacity, if I didn't mistype something in my calculator. There's often greater variability than that from one model of "same-sized" disk to another.